# NSIS - Install a file to a pre-existing, uncertain subfolder?

Tags: installation, directory, nsis

I'm trying to install a file to a pre-existing folder structured like this:

```
$APPDATA/somefolder/(uncertainFolder)
```

The "uncertainFolder" would be either "1.0" or "2.0".

The same file will be installed into the "uncertainFolder" despite the folder name difference. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt "uncertainty" is really a valid tag for this (I would guess many questioners are uncertain about many things!). Do you need to check to see if `1.0` or `2.0` exists, then chose one, or is there some other criteria?

Comment: Yes. Checking to see if either one exists and choosing one would be perfect. How can you do this?

Comment: Looks like [Locate](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Locate) in `FileFunc.nsh` or (newer) [Locate plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Locate_plugin) should be able to tell you if one of those exists. I have not used either so can't really give you any example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files installed with the `File` instruction are extracted into the directory set by `SetOutPath`. Changing this path at run-time is not a problem once you know which folder you want.

If the possible folder names are known at compile-time you can use if/or if/else:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
${If} ${FileExists} "$InstDir\SomeFolder\2.0\*.*"
    SetOutPath "$InstDir\SomeFolder\2.0"
${Else}
    SetOutPath "$InstDir\SomeFolder\1.0"
${EndIf}
```

You can also enumerate files and folders at run-time:

```
FindFirst $0 $1 "$InstDir\SomeFolder\*.*"
loop:
    StrCmp $1 "" end ; No more files?
    StrCmp $1 "." next ; DOS special name
    StrCmp $1 ".." next ; DOS special name
    IfFileExists "$InstDir\SomeFolder\$1\*.*" 0 next ; Skip files
    DetailPrint "$1 is a folder in $InstDir\SomeFolder"
    SetOutPath "$InstDir\SomeFolder\$1"
    Goto end ; This stops the search at the first folder it finds
next:
    FindNext $0 $1
    goto loop
end:
FindClose $0
```

The Locate macro in FileFunc.nsh is built on top of FindFirst/FindNext and can also be used if you prefer its syntax...

Comment: If statement worked. I set two sections for the two files that I wanted to install into two different locations.